How should now off-topic questions that were recently edited be treated?
I just came across a proposed edit in the suggested edits review queue, on an answer to an old question that is now off-topic (its about litecoin).
The edit is useful (it updates the answer to include more current segwit info), but since the question is off-topic I'm unsure what the proper course of action should be.
Screenshot with part of the edit visible, for some context:


In my opinion, it is fine to edit old questions and answers like the example you provided if they're already answered and are good questions, even if they're now off topic. If they're not closed then they might as well be correct.

Yeah, even though we don't collect more questions about altcoins, I wouldn't want to delete existing content. People spend a lot of time collecting information, and they probably still get a decent amount of hits. I'd definitely say we should merge improvements.
